# CSS/Javascript Prevent cursor style change, ondrag event

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my scratchpad http://jsbin.com/aledig/1/edit
When drawing the cursor is changed from pointer, how to prevent it?

Comment: on FX18.0.1 I always see a pointer.

Comment: hm me too, then that's issue w/ chromium

Answer (score 0):

I can not find any problem in this scratch pad. The cursor is always pointer in IE and FireFox. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a chromium's bug. Simple workaround could be to prevent default behaviour in mousedown handler, here using draw_start:

http://jsbin.com/aledig/7/edit

```
function draw_start(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
        draw(x-30, y-30, 5, 5);
        canvas.onmousemove =getmxy;
        canvas.onmousedown = getmxy;        
      }
```